# Error "was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory" on salesforce deployment

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, release-management, salesforce-communities, salesforce-sfdx

anyone here experienced facing this following issue on salesforce deployment process:

```
⁠An object '....' of type '.....' was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
```

Already looking the answer from internet but still didn't found clear solution.
And I got totally almost 1000 error like that
hope anyone can help me to fix this.

Thanks in advance ⁠

Comment: Not enough info. Which sfdx command you're using to deploy, have you verified the files are really there, retrieved from the server, no typos? How was your project created, "with manifest" (do you have package.xml in the directory or is one created on the fly during deploy). Have you tried just putting `*` wildcard instead of listing each file separately. You tagged communities - you're doing "SiteDotCom" (old school weird a$$ part json-part binary file) or "Experience Bundle" or however the newer option is called (new school bunch of small json files)

Answer (score 0):

To fix this Usually the best way is to `Git pull origin Dev` Dev is the branch you are using to create the working feature branch. It worked for me but it occured a while back again for anyone finds RCA and perma solution for this please share.